# Marionette "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'render'", with ItemView

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, marionette

In Bakbone Marionette I'm trying to display an IteView with data from the model.
The JSON data from the rest api comes fine. The problem is that whenever I try to display a view inside a region it displays the mentioned error.

This is the code:

```
TestDataModel = Backbone.Model.extend({

    url: function(){
        return '/test.php?api=getTestData
    }
});

TestDataView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({

    template: Handlebars.compile($('#testing-template').html()),

    initialize: function(){
        _.bindAll(this);

        // I want to bind render when the model changes        
        this.model.on('change', this.render, this);        

        this.model.fetch();
    }

});


<script id='testing-template' type='text/x-handlebars-template'>
    Testing template: {{test_token1}} {{test_token2}}
</script>

// this the main function that render the data on a main base page region.
onRender: function(){

    var testModel = new TestDataModel.Model();
    var testView = new TestDataView({
         model:testModel
    });
    this.test_region.show(testView);
}
```

Comment: Where is your render method defined?

Comment: @kinakuta, I don't know, that's the problem, It seems that marionette calls it, don't know if it is a problem with the version or something.
I have v1.0.0-rc3.

Comment: I'm not that familiar with Marionette, so I couldn't speak to whether it provides an override of the default, empty render method Backbone provides, but try using listenTo like I show below and if that still isn't working, implement your own render.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use onShow instead of onRender.  The region hasn't been setup yet when onRender is called

Answer (score 1):

Instead of binding on the model, try the listenTo convention:

```
TestDataView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({

    template: Handlebars.compile($('#testing-template').html()),

    initialize: function () {

        this.listenTo(this.model, 'change', this.render);

        this.model.fetch();
    }
});
```

Like I stated above, if this still isn't working, you're either missing something or you'll need to provide your own render.

Answer (score 1):

Don't call fetch from your views initializer.

```
TestDataModel = Backbone.Model.extend({

    url: function(){
        return '/test.php?api=getTestData
    }
});

TestDataView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({

    template: Handlebars.compile($('#testing-template').html()),

    initialize: function(){
        _.bindAll(this); 
        this.model.on('change', this.render, this);        
    }

});


<script id='testing-template' type='text/x-handlebars-template'>
    Testing template: {{test_token1}} {{test_token2}}
</script>

// this the main function that render the data on a main base page region.
onRender: function(){
    var self = this;
    var testModel = new TestDataModel.Model();
    var testView = new TestDataView({
         model:testModel
    });
    this.testModel.fetch().done(function(){
      self.test_region.show(testView);
    });
}
```

Comment: Where should fetch be called from?

Comment: Typically you would call it in your controller or router.